# In clause in if statement in Linux Shell

Tags: shell

I'm trying to check if python is installed on the system. if not then install it and run a given code on the machine. We have Linux servers and all servers need this script to be executed.

I'm facing a problem here, my if statement is not working. I don't know why. I'm trying to see if the echo for python --version returns "not found" but the string will be quite big, so I'm checking for a substring. Is there any "IN" statement?

Following is my Code.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Author : Sushrut Guruji
# Copyright (c) sushrut_guruji
# Script follows here:
INSTALL=$(python3 --version)
PyScriptPath="/PyScripts"

echo $INSTALL
if [[$INSTALL=~*not*found]]
then
        echo 'in if'
        sudo apt-get install python3.9
        sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
        sudo apt install -y python3-pip
        sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pi
else
        echo "in else"
fi
cd $PyScriptPath
sudo pip install -r requriements.txt
```

P.S. I'm a novice. Please don't laugh.

Comment: Do you have a question?  A problem?  Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Isn't `if [ ! -f /usr/bin/python3 ]` enough?

Comment: `[[ $INSTALL =~ *not*found ]]` spaces, spaces, spaces, and be aware, `*not*found` will be treated as an Extended REGEX -- which does not appear to do what you would want. (perhaps `not.*found` may be what you are after) Also, simple `type python` will tell you if it is installed or not.

Comment: sometimes, the python is uninstalled for a fresh installation, but the bin folders still contain /python3 or its subsidiaries. So that won't help. Checking if the system understands python is the right way to know if it's installed correctly.

Comment: ok, what does the dot(.) do after not.

Comment: This is the output that I get even after the changes.

Comment: ```/PyScripts/setup.sh: 6: python3: not found

/PyScripts/setup.sh: 10: [[: not found
in else
sudo: pip: command not found```

Comment: Your shebang says to use sh, but your script has a lot of bashisms that sh doesn't understand...

Comment: this is how my if looks like now: ```if [[$INSTALL =~ *not.*found]]```

Comment: @Susahrut **1** `$INSTALL` will not contain `not found`; it’s printed to STDERR, which `$()` doesn’t catch. **2** `[[` is a Bash thing, it won’t work in your script. **3** To check whether `python --version` works just put it in the `if` condition: `if python --version >/dev/null 2>&1`. **4** You can install multiple packages at once: `apt-get install python3.9 python3-pip` **5** Don’t use `apt` in scripts; use `apt-get`. **6** [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) is your friend.